# Div com mesma altura de imagem no Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, layout-responsivo

Tenho uma imagem a esquerda e outros 4 blocos a direita. Precisava que as quatro blocos seguissem a altura da imagem, mesmo ao mudar a resolução.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

HTML:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 img-container">
            <img class="img-responsive" src="{{ asset('storage/img4.jpg') }}" alt="...">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6 container-painel">
                    <div class="painel1">
                        <img class="img-responsive" src="{{ asset('storage/massage.png') }}">
                        <h2>Título</h2>
                        <img class="img-responsive" src="{{ asset('storage/vetor.png') }}">
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="painel3">
                        <img class="img-responsive" src="{{ asset('storage/massage.png') }}">
                        <h2>Título</h2>
                        <img class="img-responsive" src="{{ asset('storage/vetor.png') }}">
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6 container-painel">
                    <div class="painel2">
                        <img class="img-responsive" src="{{ asset('storage/massage.png') }}">
                        <h2>Título</h2>
                        <img class="img-responsive" src="{{ asset('storage/vetor.png') }}">
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="painel4">
                        <img class="img-responsive" src="{{ asset('storage/massage.png') }}">
                        <h2>Título</h2>
                        <img class="img-responsive" src="{{ asset('storage/vetor.png') }}">
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>  
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.img-container {
    padding: 0;
}

.container-painel {
   padding: 0;
}

.painel1 {
   padding: 0;
   border-bottom: 1px solid #333333;
   border-right: 1px solid #333333;
}

.painel2 {
   padding: 0;
   border-bottom: 1px solid #333333;
   border-right: 1px solid #333333;
}

.painel3 {
    padding: 0;
    border-right: 1px solid #333333;
}

.painel4 {
   padding: 0;
   border-right: 1px solid #333333;
}
```

Comment: Acho que se você não utilizar um pré-processador css como LESS ou SASS não vai funcionar. Estou tentando ver uma forma de fazer isso sem JavaScript, más esta meio difícil kkkk'
Se quiser aqui tem uma solução simples com Jquery (Se quiser responsivo só colocar dentro de um "onresize" que ele funciona normalmente)
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/dRrzKB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**O que foi feito**

Adicionei uma nova classe `adapta` em todos os 4 elementos (painel1,painel2,painel3,painel4).

Dessa forma é possível manipular todos ao mesmo tempo utilizando Jquery.

Criei a função `adapta()` para sempre que a página for carregada ou redimensionada ela entre em ação.

**Lógica da função adapta()**

Pegamos o `height` da imagem que está a esquerda, depois é só dividir por 2 e atribuir esse valor na `height` da classe `adapta` para que todas as div's a direita ocupem o `height` idêntico ao da imagem a esquerda.

```
$(document).ready(adapta);
$(document).on('resize', adapta);

function adapta()
{
  var altura = $('.img-responsive').css('height');

  var alturaF = altura.split('px');

 // alert(alturaF[0]/2);

  $('.adapta').css('height', alturaF[0]/2+'px');

};
```

*Lembre-se de inserir a classe* `adapta` *aos paineis no html.*

Comment: Acabei conseguindo fazer somente com css definindo uma altura para o container e inserindo a imagem através do css com background-image. Mas vou ficar com sua resposta para outras situações.